# How do I use a <code> tag in a table that does not wrap?

Tags: html, css, markdown, docusaurus

On my Docusaurus page, I have markup like this that renders the following screenshot:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><code>organizationName</code></td>
    <td>The GitHub user or organization that owns the repository. In the case of Docusaurus, that would be the "facebook" GitHub organization.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><code>projectName</code></td>
    <td>The name of the GitHub repository for your project. For example, Docusaurus is hosted at https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus, so our project name in this case would be "docusaurus".</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Note that the first table column are wrapped. I prefer them to not be wrapped so that it is easier to read. How do I make the `<code>` block level such that it does not wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it, each with its own tradeoffs but both produce the same result.

#### 1. Use `<pre>`

Insert `<pre>` into the `<code>`. Note that this is not the standard way of writing HTML. According to the spec, the `<code>` should be inside `<pre>` instead. This works for a Docusaurus site.

```
<td><code>organizationName</code></td>
```

would instead be written as:

```
<td><code><pre>organizationName</pre></code></td>
```

#### 2. Add custom CSS targeting `<code>` [RECOMMENDED]

Add the CSS

```
code.block {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and do:

```
<td><code class="block">organizationName</code></td>
```

The second way is cleaner and what I settled on. Since I only faced the problem when `<code>` was used as the first column in a table, I used the following CSS, which is also what [Bootstrap website](https://getbootstrap.com) uses.

```
table td:first-child > code {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The benefit of doing the above is that I can use Markdown syntax for my table and I do not have to add custom classes to it:

```
| `organizationName` | The GitHub user ... |
```

#### Final Result

[image]

Comment: don't you think that the use of `white-space: nowrap;` is well known is such situation ? so can i ask you what is the plus of creating an question/answer for it ?